# libssh/libssh.h not found on Windows 10 using gcc

Tags: windows, libssh

I'm trying to use libssh on Windows 10 with gcc.  The work is being done from the command line.

I don't know how to make **libssh/** part of the search path.

The #include was **libssh/libssh.h**, but that failed. (The brackets were left out of this sentence.)

```
#include <libssh.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  ssh_session my_ssh_session = ssh_new();
  if (my_ssh_session == NULL)
    exit(-1);
  ...
  ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
}
```

When I modify the include statement to be just **libssh.h** and use the following on the command line:

> **gcc -IC:\libssh\include\libssh ssh.c -oout.exe**

That works to get past the libssh.h file not found.

But, the other files that are called, such as **libssh/legacy.h** are not found.

How do I get the **libssh** to be part of the search path?

I added *c:\libssh\include\libssh* to the environment path.  That didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to let `#include <libssh/libssh.h>`
because libssh.h call a header legacy.h which is also located in the libssh folder so if you put directly the header libssh.h it won't be able to locate legacy.h

```
#include <libssh/libssh.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  ssh_session my_ssh_session = ssh_new();
  if (my_ssh_session == NULL)
    exit(-1);
  // remove the dots it'll create an error
  ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
}
```

to have libssh a part of the path you should do 
**gcc -I/path/to/libssh/include/directory -L/path/to/libssh/lib/directory -lssh ssh.c oout.exe**

I also got stuck into that, now I face another issue, the one to link the libssh.dll or ssh.dll inside the compiled code to use it as stand-alone.

Comment: Thank you.  I will give that a try.